# Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime()

Tags: php

So, on my website I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in /homepages/4/d661770438/htdocs/awptical/initdata.php:382 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/4/d661770438/htdocs/awptical/index.php(21): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /homepages/4/d661770438/htdocs/awptical/initdata.php on line 382
```

Does anybody know what this means?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? This function no longer exists in PHP 7

Comment: I'm using webhosting, anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Depends on one *very* important question: is your code using this function as `set_magic_quotes_runtime(true)` or as `set_magic_quotes_runtime(false)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The function no longer exists in PHP 7, nor the setting it works with, so you will need to remove its usages. You will need to save the current state of your code and try to remove all the instances of this `function` call and see whether the site is working and if so, whether it is working as you expect it to work. Alternatively, you can implement a dummy version of the `function` and make it available everywhere:

```
if (!function_exists('set_magic_quotes_runtime')) {
    function set_magic_quotes_runtime($new_setting) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the caveat that if your code depended on `set_magic_quotes_runtime(true)`, you're SOL and will have to rewrite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP version 7.x.x, at which [set_magic_quotes_runtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php) was **removed**.

`This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.`

Comment: I'm using webhosting, anyway I can fix this?

Comment: @JohnCena — Rewrite your code so it doesn't depend on features that have been marked Do Not Use since 2014.

Comment: And if I have 10 websites which no one wants to rewrite since 2014 and there is no php5 hosting around?